# PHP: append to value if the key already exist, if not add the key

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking for a succinct way of doing this in PHP:

given an array, if I add one `key=>value` pair to it, the routine should check whether the key already exist.

If it doesn't exist, add to the array with the `key=>value` pair.

If it does, then the value should be append to the value of the array. So, for example, if the initial array is this

```
arr['a']='2e'
```

When I add a `'a'=>'45'` pair to the array, then the routine will return me

```
arr['a']=array('2e', '45')
```

When I add another `'a=>gt'` pair to it, then the routine will return me

```
arr['a']=array('2e', '45','gt')
```

Is there a succinct way of doing this? Of course I can write it myself but I believe my solution is very ugly.

Comment: You should clarify something, do you really want arr['a']='2e' at the begining, or is it a typo and you expect arr['a']=array('2e') ?

Comment: Both would do-- I don't care which is the case

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could solve the problem, by using an array for the first element ("2e") aswell:

```
$arr = array();

$arr['a'][] = '2e';
$arr['a'][] = '45';
$arr['a'][] = 'gt';

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Good that it does not throw any notice/warning if key ['a'] does not exist and eventually creates that key.

Answer (score 14):

There are three situations:

1. The key is undefined
2. The key is defined, but isn't yet set to an array
3. The key is defined, and the element is an array.

So, in code:

```
function appendThings(/* map[string,mixed] */ $array, /* string */ $key, /* string */ $value) {
    if (!isset($array[$key]))
        $array[$key] = $value;
    else if (is_array($array[$key]))
        $array[$key][] = $value;
    else
        $array[$key] = array($array[$key], $value);

    return $array;
}
```

It's only the last case that's tricky: if it's not an array yet, you'll need to compose one using the current value plus the new one.

Comment: Note that this function does not return anything so it would be nice to return this array or use `&$array` on parameters list.

Answer (score 3):

```
function update_keypair($arr, $key, $val)
{
   if(empty($arr[$key])) $arr[$key] = array($val);
   else $arr[$key][] = $val;
}
```

does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function that does that. Or initialize your first element as an array as well and use array_push function to add new elements.

```
$a = array('2e');
array_push($a, '45');
array_push($a, 'gt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$key="a";
$value="b";
$array=array();

if(!array_key_exists($key,$array)) $array[$key]=$value;
elseif(is_array($array[$key]))$array[$key][]=$value;
else $array[$key]=array($array[$key],$value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($array[$key]) {
  if (!is_array($array[$key]))
    $array[$key] = (array)$array[$key];
  $array[$key][] = $new_value;
} else {
  $array[$key] = $new_value;
}
```

Something like that? You can surely simplify this by adding first value as an one-element array, or by using ternar operators, but anyway you'll need a custom function to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly array:

```
$arr['a']=(is_array($arr['a'])? '2e' : array_merge(Array('2e'),$arr['a']));
```

String with separators:

```
$arr['a'].='2e'.'/'; // '/' is used as a separator in here.
```

if you need the string as an array just do `$arr['a'] = explode("/",$arr['a']);`

both methods are ugly... you should try, as FlorianH suggested, to use the whole variable as an array.

Another method might be to use the Interface in PHp and build something that make suse of the Iterator and ArrayAccess interfaces. (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)